# Need a program to exit after hitting a character python

Tags: python, for-loop

My script first reads a data file and then proceeds to analyze/plot it. I want the program to read the file line by line and then stop looking for lines upon hitting a # in the data file, at which point I'd like it to continue on the the rest it's code (plotting/analyzing, etc). I've been looking around and have tried `sys.exit()` and `break` but they don't allow for the program to continue on to it's analytic process, it just exits. Totally lost.

For more info....

```
for i in range(WL):
if(data[i][0]=='#'):comments=comments+1
else:
 #analytic stuff
 #more stuff
```

That was what was originally written in. This isn't my stuff, so I'm finding I get errors with this format, I'd like to revamp it and make the # a termination character.
After trying @Lev_Levitsky's suggestion I now get an error of the type

```
flux=np.append(flux,data[i][1])
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Why would that happen?

Here's the new look

```
for i in range(WL):
 if '#' in line:
   break
 else:
  #analyze
```

Comment: `break` is *exactly* what you need. What did you try with that that didn't work?

Comment: Next time around, post your code!

Comment: @Matt: and where is your `break`?

Comment: @MartijnPieters Sorry, re-edited.

Comment: @Matt `line` wouldn't be defined in your edited code. You are copy-pasting code without understanding what it does...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`break` is what you need. It will take you out of the loop where you read lines from the file, and take you to whatever is after the loop:

```
with open('data') as f:
    for line in f:
       if '#' in line:
           break
       # do something else in the loop
       # like append something to a list

# analyze the data
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on what you just showed us, what you want to do is this:

```
for i in range(WL):
    if(data[i][0]=='#'):
        comments=comments+1
        break
    else:
        #analytic stuff
        #more stuff
```

This is exactly the same as what Lev suggested, except I've spelled out explicitly where to put your break.

Comment: Thank you. I know it's annoying to deal with less-than explicit people like myself. Again, appreciate the help.

Comment: @Matt although sometimes answers which show a concept which would fix the problem but do not offer the solution in the context of the question can be frustrating, this is an elementary example; you need to take some time to try to implement the solution offered correctly, rather than just copy-pasting code and expecting it to work.